# Rspec expect success message

Tags: rspec, rspec3

Is possible to add a success message to a expect result?
I know how to add a custom error message

```
expect(true).to be(true), "Expect true to be true"
```

But i want to add a message when expect goes well, for example:

```
expect(true).to be(true), "Expect true to be true"

>>Expect true to be true - Test passed
```

Comment: `it "expect true to be true" do ...` that's how you do it in RSpec, no other ways.

Comment: So if an "it" contains multiple expectations you cannot log the success of each one, only the whole "it"?

Comment: Check this, [Single expectation test](http://www.betterspecs.org/) - each test should make only one assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way - to use expectation description block (`it '...' do`). Also, according to [Single expectation test](http://www.betterspecs.org/) - each test should make only one assertion, try to avoid using a few expectations. Only when you check ONE thing, so the name should be one also. Or better add context/describe block and few assertions there in separated blocks.